# Programmatically creating a NSImageView in Swift 3.0

Tags: xcode, swift, nsimageview

According to the documentation here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImageView_Class/

I have tried programmatically creating a NSImage view:

```
var thing = NSImageView.init(frame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 256, 256))

thing.image = NSImage(named:"test.png")
```

It runs without any errors in Xcode and successfully creates the view, but nothing can be seen in the view controller anywhere.

I also want to add the following parameters to the view but Xcode cannot find them:

```
thing.editable:"YES"

thing.animates:"YES"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you haven't added it to the window yet.

If you use storyboard:

```
self.view.addSubview(thing)
```

If you use the traditional XIB:

```
self.window.contentView?.addSubview(thing)
```

Also, you got the names of the two properties wrong. They should be:

```
thing.isEditable = true
thing.animates = true
```

Comment: Thank you. This works! When I have enough rep points, this will upvoted.